# Using traditional foreach loop replace an item at specific index in List in C#

Tags: c#

Here is my code to figure out the issue.
**Error Detail:** Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.

```
List<string> mylist = new List<string>();
mylist.Add("Val1");
mylist.Add("Val2");
mylist.Add("Val3");

int i = 1;
int totalLenngth = mylist.Count;
foreach (var item in mylist)
{
    if (i == totalLenngth) {
      //mylist.Remove(bro);
        mylist.RemoveAt(i);
        mylist.Add("Val4");
    }
    i++;
}
```

Comment: You should not be using a `foreach` loop in the first place. Use `foreach` when you want to READ each item from a list and use it. You should be using a `for` loop. Use the correct loop for the job at hand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75968975/7186739

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently, this code `does not need a loop`. It also does not need `Insert` and `Remove`. Just replace the value!

```
mylist[targetIndex] = "val4";
```

Comment: Specifically `mylist[mylist.Count-1] = "val4";`

Answer (score 2):

The line `brothers.RemoveAt(i)` is the one throwing the `Index Out of Bounds Exception`. This is because that method uses the zero based index to locate the `val3` element in the list and the index 3 will be out of bounds as the index of the last element in your list is 2. If you wish to remove a certain element in the list and replace it with another then the code below would be effective.

```
    List<string> brothers = new List<string>();
    brothers.Add("Val1");
    brothers.Add("Val2");
    brothers.Add("Val3");
    //get the index of the item you desire 
    var targetIndex = brothers.IndexOf("Val3");
    //replace the item with an item of your choice
    brothers.Insert(targetIndex, "new value");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use loop only to read the values.

```
List<string> myList = new List<string>();
    myList.Add("Val1");
    myList.Add("Val2");
    myList.Add("Val3");
    myList[myList.Count - 1] = "Val4";
    foreach (var item in myList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item);
            }
```

Credit goes to @Hossein Sabziani to simplify the answer.

Comment: While this may fix the runtime exception, this is an unnecessarily complex solution. Just go with the suggested `myList[targetIndex]` approach, or use a `for` loop with an index. Your question nor your answer show a necessity to do it this way.

Comment: It's Hossein's answer demonstrating this already, credits go to them.

Comment: Do not forget to accept Hossein's answer.